# Why do we need 3 areas in Young Generation for Garbage Collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm

I know that young generation is divided into Eden, From, To areas.
But could anyone explain to me is that OK if we have only 2 areas, like 1st area, 2nd area?

I think we still can do copy Garbage Collection with only 2 areas, as below.

1. New objects come => place them on 1st
2. When 1st is full, copy live ones to 2nd and delete all on 1st
3. New objects come again => place them on 2nd
4. When 2nd is full, copy live ones to 1st and delete them on 2nd
   and so on

So, why do we even need an extra (Eden) area?

Is that better for performance?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't need *any* separate areas. Experience has shown that having three provides the best performance for most real-world uses.

Comment: I understand that 3 areas is good, since it is being used world-wide. I just want to know the reason.

Comment: Because most objects are discarded almost immediately, so it makes sense to segregate long-lived objects in their own area to minimize the need to copy.

Comment: I think that is the purpose of dividing Heap into Young and Old. What I don't understand is to moreover, divide Young into 3 areas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your scheme objects cannot occupy more than a half of Young Gen, so 50% of Young Gen memory is always wasted.

Separate To and From spaces are usually smaller than Eden. This helps to reduce memory overhead while retaining the benefits of the fast copying collector.